# How do I continue entering commands into Bash once I've opened a document?

Tags: bash, command-line

If I type in, for example:

```
    $ notepad.exe web-dev.txt
```

web-dev.txt obviously opens with notepad. But if I go back into my command line, I'm unable to write any more commands until I close notepad. The command line is just black with no $.

Can I not give any more commands until I'm done with that task?

Comment: `notepad.exe web-dev.txt &` should do the trick?

Comment: If you forget the `&` you can still type the `control-z` character, then the command `bg` and this will have the same effect if the command is still running.

Comment: For me, control-z just gave me the response 'Stopped', and notepad closed as soon as I pressed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`notepad.exe web-dev.txt &` will run the command in the background and you can keep on working.
Use `jobs` to see the commands running in the background.

This documentation could be helpful: http://linuxreviews.org/beginner/jobs